# syntactical error in SQL regarding my if else statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an error regarding the syntax of my else statement.

Here is my code

```
 DECLARE @var VARCHAR(20) = (SELECT TOP 1 name FROM store2)

 DECLARE @i int = 1
 DECLARE @incr int
 DECLARE @y VARCHAR(20)
 WHILE @i < 5
 BEGIN
     SET @y = (SELECT name FROM store1 WHERE id = @i);    
     IF @y = @var
     SET @incr = (SELECT count FROM store1 WHERE id = @i)+1
     PRINT N'TRUE';

     ELSE
     PRINT 'FALSE';



 SET @i = @i + 1
 END
```

Comment: If you have *more than one* statement after your `IF`, you **must use** a `BEGIN .... END` block ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bit of proper **indenting**, the error would become very obvious:

```
 DECLARE @var VARCHAR(20) = (SELECT TOP 1 name FROM store2)

 DECLARE @i int = 1
 DECLARE @incr int
 DECLARE @y VARCHAR(20)

 WHILE @i < 5
 BEGIN
     SET @y = (SELECT name FROM store1 WHERE id = @i);    

     IF @y = @var
         SET @incr = (SELECT count FROM store1 WHERE id = @i)+1

     PRINT N'TRUE';

     ELSE
         PRINT 'FALSE';

     SET @i = @i + 1
 END
```

If you have an `IF`, then **only** the next statement is executed inside that `IF` block - any further statement (including your `ELSE`....) is outside the `IF` block - **unless** you add `BEGIN ... END` to it - like this:

```
     IF @y = @var
     BEGIN
         SET @incr = (SELECT count FROM store1 WHERE id = @i)+1
         PRINT N'TRUE';
     END
     ELSE
         PRINT 'FALSE';
```